# php script cant read xml data with colon (:)

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

**I tried to read youtube xml data width php but stuck because youtube uses colon (:)in his API
To be precise, here is script I use:**

```
$video = array('/some arrays here,separated width commas/');// array of youtube videos

$v = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\_]/","",$_GET["v"]); // make sure "v" parameter is sanitized

if(!empty($v) && in_array($v,$video)){ //check if parameter "v" is empty and is yours video
    echo('<object width="853" height="505"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$v.'&hl=en_US&fs=1&hd=1&color1=0xe1600f&color2=0xfebd01"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$v.'&hl=en_US&fs=1&hd=1&color1=0xe1600f&color2=0xfebd01" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="853" height="505"></embed></object>');     
}else{
    foreach($video as $v){
        echo('
        <div class="tube"><a href="/pages/tube.php?v='.$v.'" class="thickbox"><img style="border:2px solid #000;margin:5px;" alt="" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/'.$v.'/default.jpg"/></a>');
        $xmlData = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$v.'?fields=title,yt:recorded'));//it should be working if I add fields just separated width commas

        $title = (string)$xmlData->title;
        $recorded = (string)$xmlData->recorded;//It should be yt:recorded but I understand that cant use : here!

        {        echo '<p>'.$recorded.' '.$title.'</p></div>';    }
    }
}
```

It works fine width just title. Is it possible to read somehow yt:recorded

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the namespace first before trying to access it's values. Have a look at the method [`getNamespaces`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php). Using `children` you can then access values inside a namespace:

```
$namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);
$yr = $entry->children($namespaces['yt']); 
echo $yr->recorded;
```

Comment: I am following the 1st example given in  http://de2.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php . It works if I use the same `xml` as given in that example. But does not work for my xml. I want to parse the content inside `<q:content></q:content>` tags in `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<q:response xmlns:q="some link">
<q:impression>
<q:content>
<html>
</html>
</q:content>
<q:cpc>0.02</q:cpc>
</q:impression>
<q:app_stats>
<q:total>
<q:ctr>0</q:ctr>
<q:ecpm>0.0</q:ecpm>
</q:total>
<q:today>
<q:ctr>0</q:ctr>
<q:ecpm>0.0</q:ecpm>
</q:today>
</q:app_stats>
</q:response>`  Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665222/unable-to-parse-xml-data-with-colon-from-response-using-getnamespaces