# How to parse this XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

I need to parse the following XML file below:

https://www.performanceexchange.com/publisher/report/api/17adeb41da1343209a32e6790ee1a286/xml/report/stats?startDate=2012-07-01&endDate=2012-08-13

`$xml = simplexml_load_file( urlencode($mediatrust_url) );`

Which outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [name] => StatsReport
    )

)
```

So it seems that it just picks up the name of the first tag.

Comment: you don't need to urlencode(). That url is also not outputting valid XML, so no surprise you're not getting much.

Comment: I see no XML at the given link.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach($xml->attributes() as $k => $v)
{
    if($k == "name")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Also, try using loading the XML string like this:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string(@file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: ok got rid of the urlencode, the XML url is https://www.performanceexchange.com/publisher/report/api/17adeb41da1343209a32e6790ee1a286/xml/report/stats?startDate=2012-07-01&endDate=2012-08-13

Comment: You need to fetch the namespaces first.   This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801089/php-script-cant-read-xml-data-with-colon